# Set layer rendering 'refresh layer at interval (seconds)' using PyQGIS from python console?

Tags: pyqgis, rendering, qgis-python-console, refresh

I am trying to use the python console to achieve the following manual procedure of setting each layer to refresh automatically at a specified time interval.

The manual process:
Layer Properties > Rendering > [tick box] Refresh layer at interval (seconds) > [enter seconds].

How do I do this from the python console?

This specific rendering information is not stored in a style, and manually setting it for each new layer is time consuming. I often reload all of my layers into a new QGIS project, so being able to set the refresh interval rate with python will save a lot of time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For set this property you need to change its value in the QGIS settings

```
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QSettings
QSettings().setValue("/qgis/map_update_interval", 150)
```

For set **Refresh layer at interval (seconds)** using PyQgis you need:

```
# Get layer by name
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('pipelines')[0]

# Enabled auto refresh
layer.setAutoRefreshEnabled(True)

# Set seconds (5 seconds)
layer.setAutoRefreshInterval(5000)
```

API reference [setAutoRefreshInterval()](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsMapLayer.html#aa709dde27b7cc2b0c7507bd7b3eecafb)

Comment: Thanks for your post. Unfortunately this isn't what i was after. I want to update the refresh interval rate for the layer, not the map update interval.

If you follow the path mentioned above: 
Layer Properties > Rendering > [tick box] Refresh layer at interval (seconds) > [enter seconds].

It is this that i am trying to set from the python console.

Comment: Ah okey!Update my answer

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much.

Something worth noting: I found that the setAutoRefreshEnabled(True) only worked after an existing value was assigned to it from the setAutoRefreshInterval. 

Therefore I switched the order around:
1st
layer.setAutoRefreshInterval(5000)

2nd
layer.setAutoRefreshEnabled(True)